# R Shiny : Write looped reactive inputs to textfile

Tags: r, text-files, shiny

I am currently working on a project in which a user, inputs into the app a set of editrules for an uploaded data set. The user inputs the rule through a textbox input in the UI. I planned to create a text file which contains the editrules set by the user.

Now, my problem is creating a code which creates a list or a vector that contains these editrules since I cant think of a way to insert the user's input into the code. Here is what I have done:

```
textprepGen <- function(x,y,z){
  for(i in 1:x){
    z[[i]] <- paste(y[1], paste("input", 
                                paste("input",i, sep = "_"), sep = "$"), sep = " ") 
  }
  return(z)
}
```

The reason it does not work is because the paste function automatically sets the code into character so it does not read the input, input$input_1, input$input_2, ...

Any suggestions?

Here is the UI and the Server:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme="bootstrap.css",

                  titlePanel("Edit Rules"),

                  sidebarPanel(

                    fileInput('file_upload', 'Upload CSV File',
                              accept=c('text/csv', 
                                       'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                       '.csv')),  

                    uiOutput("editrulePanel")

                  ),

                  mainPanel(
                    h4("Data Summary")

                  )
)
)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Text input list assignment in order for the data to show up in UI
  textinpList <-vector("list", 20)

  # Textfile preparation for the lines to be written on the textfile    
  textprepList <- vector(20)

  # Function to generate text inputs
  ## A for loop is used to generate only the columns that are in the data file
  textinpGeneration <- function(x,y,z){
    for(i in 1:x){
      z[[i]] <- list(textInput(paste("text", i, sep = "_"), 
                               label = h5(y[i]), 
                               value = ">= 0"
      )
      )
    }
    return(z)
  }

  textprepGen <- function(x,y,z){
    for(i in 1:x){
      z[[i]] <- paste(y[1], paste("input", 
                                  paste("input",i, sep = "_"), sep = "$"), sep = " ") 
    }
    return(z)
  }


  # Dynamic UI
  output$editrulePanel <- renderUI ({
    # Assigns the input of the uploaded data to a variable

    inFile <- input$file_upload

    # If no file is uploaded, no table will be displayed in the main panel

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    # Read csv file uploaded

    dataFile <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)

    # Count the number of columns of the data file and assign to a variable
    ## This is used to know the number of options 
    ## to show in the editrule panel

    dataCol <- as.numeric(ncol(dataFile))

    # Read the column names and assign to a variable

    datacolName <- colnames(dataFile)

    textprepGen(dataCol, datacolName, textprepList)

    # Conditional panel for editrules show if a file has been uploaded

    conditionalPanel(condition = "is.null(inFile) == FALSE",
                     h4("Please input edit rule"),
                     textinpGeneration(dataCol,datacolName,textinpList)
    )

  })

  # Preparation for writing a textfile
  editruleFile <- file("editrules.txt")
  writeLines(c(textprepList), editruleFile)
  close(editruleFile)


})
```

The result textfile I wanted to achieve:

```
# numerical rules
RECOV <= 0
PAID >= 0
CASE >= 0
INC >= 0
```

Only the logical symbols and the number is the user input.

Comment: _I cant think of a way to insert the user's input into the code_  -You can do eval(parse(text))

Comment: Thank you! It evaluated the input! :) Though I have a problem now when I write it into a text file. There are spaces before the lines. How do I fix this?

Comment: I can take a look later if you post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, thank you so much Eugene Choe. Just got my code working. Also figured it out to write it in the textfile properly.

Here is the final code for the inputs:

```
for(i in 1:addruleNumber){
                                              textprepList[i+1+dataCol] <- list(paste(
                                                eval(parse(text =  paste("input", 
                                                                         paste("lhand",i,sep="_"), 
                                                                         sep = "$"))),
                                                eval(parse(text =  paste("input", 
                                                                         paste("logexp",i,sep="_"), 
                                                                         sep = "$"))),
                                                eval(parse(text =  paste("input", 
                                                                         paste("rhand",i,sep="_"), 
                                                                         sep = "$"))),
                                                sep = " "))
                                            }
```

And here is how I fixed the textfile output:

```
textprepList[1] <- "# numerical rules"  
                                          for(i in 1:dataCol){
                                            textprepList[i+1] <- list(paste(datacolName[i],
                                                                            eval(parse(text =  paste("input", 
                                                                                                     paste("text",i,sep="_"), 
                                                                                                     sep = "$"))), sep = " "))
                                          }
```